# Getting inconsistent raster output from gdal_calc.py raster calculation

Tags: raster, gdal, raster-calculator, numpy, gdal-calc

I'm attempting to do what is generally a straightforward raster calculation when I do this in QGIS, but am trying to do this with gdal_calc.py in terminal. The output is close, but produces banding and inconsistencies in parts of the output raster. I'm wondering if there is anything I'm overlooking. Code to calculate the image is below:

```
gdal_calc.py -A <input>  --outfile = <output> --calc="(A/nanmax(A)) * 65535" --NoDataValue=0
```

[image: Output elevation raster of clipped area. Raster shows some banding and inconsistent values in areas of the raster]

Comment: You should precise what format your input is.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain further or point me to the documentation I would need to complete your suggestion?

Comment: Use gdalinfo <dataset_name> to describe the dataset.

Comment: Also, it is always a good idea to increase the memory available to gdal, see here https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions

Comment: `Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: maryland.tiff
Size is 15978, 6520
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["NAD83",
    DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
        SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010042,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
Pixel Size = (0.000277777777896,-0.000277777777896)
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Band 1 Block=15978x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-9999`